# Task cancelled immediately when calling an async function within unit test?

Tags: f#, xunit

I'm struggling to figure out why my task is getting cancelled.

```
[<Fact>]
let ``Query applicant count``() =

    async {

        // Test
        let! response = WebGateway.get EventStore.endpoint "ApplicantCountFn" // Can't get beyond this

        // Verify
        match! response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()  |> Async.AwaitTask with
        | "" -> Assert.True (false, "result is empty")
        | _  -> ()
    }
```

**Observations:**

I verified that the server returns a successful result.

Here's the error on the client-side test:

```
  Message: 
    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : A task was canceled.
  Stack Trace: 
    TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

**Appendix:**

```
let get baseAddress (resource:string) =

    async {
        let client = httpClient baseAddress
        return! client.GetAsync(resource) |> Async.AwaitTask
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I increased the timeout for my client request to 30 seconds:

```
let client = new HttpClient(handler)
client.Timeout     <- TimeSpan(0,0,30)
```